# Slideshow display images filename on button icon before click it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Example: I have 3 images name: **Image1.png**, **Image2.png**, **Image3.png** inside a slideshow. If slideshow current display **Image2**, is it possible to show the name of **Image1.png** and **Image3.png** inside *back/forward button*?

like this [RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TG8m.png)

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var pages = $('#container li'),
    current = 0;
  var currentPage, nextPage;

  $('#container .button').click(function() {
    currentPage = pages.eq(current);
    if ($(this).hasClass('prevButton')) {

      if (current <= 0)
        current = pages.length - 1;
      else
        current = current - 1;
    } else {
      if (current >= pages.length - 1)
        current = 0;
      else
        current = current + 1;
    }
    nextPage = pages.eq(current);
    currentPage.hide();
    nextPage.show();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 1682px;
  height: 1080px;
  position: relative;
}

#container .prevButton {
  height: 68px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/wGfzuSp.png') no-repeat;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -36px;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-position: left top;
  left: 35%;
}


/*#container .prevButton:hover{ background-position:left bottom;left:0;}*/

#container .nextButton {
  height: 68px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/SWRSzhE.png') no-repeat;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -36px;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-position: right top;
  right: 35%;
}


/*#container .nextButton:hover{background-position:right bottom;right:0;}*/

#container ul {
  width: 1682px;
  height: 1080px;
  list-style: none outside none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container li:first-child {
  display: list-item;
  position: absolute;
}

#container li {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <div id="container">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2deLsUhb.jpg" width="1920" height="1080"></li>
      <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/w8Jydunb.jpg" width="1920" height="1080"></li>
      <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/CFXBhjtb.jpg " width="1920" height="1080"></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="button prevButton"></span>
    <span class="button nextButton"></span>
  </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var prevIndex = 0;
  var nextIndex = 1;
  var pages = $('#container li'),
    current = 0;
  var currentPage, nextPage;
  prevIndex = pages.length - 1;

  $('.prevButton').html($(pages[prevIndex]).attr('name'));
  $('.nextButton').html($(pages[nextIndex]).attr('name'));
  $('#container .button').click(function() {
    currentPage = pages.eq(current);
    if ($(this).hasClass('prevButton')) {

      if (current <= 0)
        current = pages.length - 1;
      else
        current = current - 1;
    } else {
      if (current >= pages.length - 1)
        current = 0;
      else
        current = current + 1;
    }
    if (current <= 0)
      prevIndex = pages.length - 1;
    else prevIndex = current - 1;
    if (current >= pages.length - 1)
      nextIndex = 0;
    else
      nextIndex = current + 1;
    $('.prevButton').html($(pages[prevIndex]).attr('name'));
    $('.nextButton').html($(pages[nextIndex]).attr('name'));
    nextPage = pages.eq(current);
    currentPage.hide();
    nextPage.show();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 1682px;
  height: 1080px;
  position: relative;
}

#container .prevButton {
  height: 68px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/wGfzuSp.png') no-repeat;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -36px;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-position: left top;
  left: 35%;
}


/*#container .prevButton:hover{ background-position:left bottom;left:0;}*/

#container .nextButton {
  height: 68px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/SWRSzhE.png') no-repeat;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -36px;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-position: right top;
  right: 35%;
}


/*#container .nextButton:hover{background-position:right bottom;right:0;}*/

#container ul {
  width: 1682px;
  height: 1080px;
  list-style: none outside none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container li:first-child {
  display: list-item;
  position: absolute;
}

#container li {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <div id="container">
    <ul>
      <li name="img1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2deLsUhb.jpg" width="1920" height="1080"></li>
      <li name="img2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/w8Jydunb.jpg" width="1920" height="1080"></li>
      <li name="img3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/CFXBhjtb.jpg " width="1920" height="1080"></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="button prevButton"></span>
    <span class="button nextButton"></span>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: my God, you sir are a genius, this code work like charm. Thank you very much!
where did you learn all this things? :D

Comment: If you want to learn about front-end, i think this [code camp](https://www.freecodecamp.com) is an awesome place to do it. If my answer solve your problem, please accept it. Glad to help!

Comment: yeah sure, i'm trying to find that accept button, i'm also new to this site, although i used to searching for answer (without asking) a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use bootstrap carousels for that. And to display the name of prev and forward images you can replace the previous and forward symbols with required name or images.

Comment: Yes, i know everything is easy with bootstrap, but i'm kinda new at this, and it's my training so i'm only allow to use basic language like html, javascript - no tools